# How can I get involved in online medical research?

Tags: research

I am a medical student. I want to get involved in online medical research but i don't know where to start or if online medical researches even exist. so Please tell me what to do or what are the organisations that provide this kind of research.

Comment: I'm glad you are enthusiastic for this. Could you clarify what type of research you have in mind? Perhaps data analysis that can be done online, or are you trying to contact researchers online for research that you can do locally?  In any case, talking with your instructors should be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

As a medical student contact professors at your school directly

I am touch with Tens of M.D. professors world-wide since I read, preview  100+ research papers every month and contact researchers, professors immediately.

But in medicine, research is done locally, so it's hard to image remote engagement.

I completed covid detection, protection, microbiology copurses at WHO Geneva in Fabruary 2020, teamed with 200+ medical practitioners at WHO, read latest covid R&D papers from Wuhan Institute of Virology, contact Sauci, EMA, WHO

since a single research paper in medicine published in Nature can disclose state-of-the-art in covid antibodies art and there is a team behind every papers, donated and funded but there is always team leader to contact to.

I can open research groups for students of medicine at WHO for on-line chat, team hiring and more and can ask head of WHO, Tedros to give detailed opinion for students of medicine.

wish you all the best
darius

Comment: I recommend editing your answer and deleting everything after the first sentence.